# Issue passing response values as header values for sub sequent calls in Jmeter REST api testing

Tags: jmeter

I have an Authenticate method that calls the Service and gets the response, i use those response object(token in response) and insert them into regular exp variables

(BeanShell Post processing of authenticate method code below)

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Token",vars.get("Token")));
```

But i see i get an error below. Not sure where exactly is the issue i guess it is not able to identify the sampler class or the getHeaderManager() method
Note: My authentication call succeeds and get a response

ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;  sampler.getHeaderManager . . . '' : Attempt to resolve method: getHeaderManager() on undefined variable or class name: sampler

Anyhelp is highly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unlike [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor), [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) doesn't have an access to previous `sampler` object, so `sampler` is indeed undefined. Also I think your intention is to add that header to the following samplers, not to the current one (which already finished running). So instead of having post-processor on the sampler which retrieves the token, you need to have a **Beanshell PreProcessor on each sampler afterwards** with the same code.

Comment: Thanks Kiril S. for the response, Seems what you made is a right point. But i wanted to extract the Token from response data. If i remove the sampler code from PostProcessioning section of authentication method, How do i get the values used(used in header) for next calls?  Like the next call GetCustomerbyID(id) takes the token in the header but i see vars.get("Token") is not assigned to any value. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: @Bala The code you posted does not extract token from the response data. It takes the value of `Token` variable (must be stored prior to that by some other post-processor) and tries to store its value in the header of the sampler. From what you've wrote, it looked like you are saving that variable using regex extractor. So what is it that you are trying to do: save data from sampler response into variable (which the code you posted does not do at all), or add its value to header of the following request (which code you posted is doing, but only in pre-processor as I explained)?

Comment: Thanks Kiril S. for the response. Yes as you mentioned i am using an regularExp  extractor for extracting the Token from the Authenticate method response data(body) but i dont see it's getting the value into the vars. i checked it using the log.info.  If i get the Token extracted from the Authenticate response data then i would like to add that into header of sampler for next request,. I am new to JMeter so was looking for some help

Comment: @Bala: if Variable does not contain data, you should first see if the response contained it (or was it a cookie for example) using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree); if response contains it, but variable does not, you can debug your RegEx using the same View Results Tree.
Once variable is saving correctly, use the code you show above in pre-processor for the next and every request.
If, however, the Token is passed as a Cookie, use Cookie Manager instead. Then you don't need those pre- and post-processors at all.

Comment: Thanks Kiril S. for the response, You investigation steps are helpful, But i solved the issue, Seems my Regex extractor are  configured for the JSON response , Somehow that got removed, If i keep the Accept Parameter as Application my Regex was about to extract the data. Anyway your help was amazing and thanks . So Suggestion for novice like me to check the accept type if your regex do not work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ctx.getCurrentSampler()` instead of `sampler` in case of Beanshell PostProcessor

See:

- [JMeterContext class JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getCurrentSampler())
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide

Also keep in mind that PostProcessor is executed **after** the sampler so the parent sampler will not be affected by header change.